# Permission denied or Something when trying to run PHP script as a CRONJOB to create a .txt file

Tags: php, apache, cron, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to run a PHP script located at `var/www/html/CronScripts/` as a cronjob. All this script does is create a `.txt` or `.out` file in the same directory. Here is the script:

```
 <?php 

$handle = fopen("theFileHandle.out", "a");
fwrite($handle, "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.\n");
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Now the problem is that, when I execute this script by opening it in the browser, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: fopen(theFileHandle.out): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/CronScripts/index.php on line 3

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/CronScripts/index.php on line 4

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/CronScripts/index.php on line 5
```

SO my inference was that if this script is run as **`sudo`**, there won't be PERMISSION PROBLEMS; and since I am ultimately going to run the script in a cronjob, I executed the following command in terminal

```
sudo crontab -e
```

to add the follwoing cronjob to **`sudo`** user's crontab file.

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/CronScripts/index.php > /var/www/html/CronScripts/output.out
```

After this, a file named `output.out` WAS created ** BUT IT WAS EMPTY.

THEN from my websearch I concluded that I was adding cronjob to sudo user's crontab, but apache2/php are run by user **`www-data`**, so that is probably the problem. So I switched user to `www-data` by executing `su -s /bin/bash www-data` and then to its crontab I added `* * * * * php /var/www/html/CronScripts/index.php > /var/www/html/CronScripts/out.out` BUT the output log file `out.out` is never created.

**So my question is that why am I facing this problem and how do I solve this?**

Comment: in the first case when you execute sudo... are there errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log ? And what is the output of this command line : ls -la /var/www/html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original problem seems that the user www-data (the one executing apache and so the php script) does not have rights to write in the directory. You can solve that with chown and chmod, giving permission to read and write to the www-data user in this directory.

That solution could be a security problems, consider using a directory out of the scope of the apache server (e.g /varr/www/anotherplace) and ensure that you dont give execution rights to the files your script create.